# Problem when trying to unnest sf object using tidyr

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, unnest

I'm trying to unnest a list-column containing sf objects (xy/ point coordinates).

I have a dataframe with three cities and a list-column containing the location of supermarkets in each city. I would like to unnest these to give a sf object where each row represents on supermarket.

I am getting the following error `Error in attributes(lst) <- a :  'names' attribute [32] must be the same length as the vector [0]`

I have read that unnest can handle sf objects, but am I getting an error because unnest() doesn't know what to name each observation? Could anyone point me in the right direction of a fix?

Thanks

I'm using unnest() from Tidyverse v. 1.3.1 as follows:

```
taiwan %>% unnest(cols = osm_points)
```

And my the data.frame *taiwan* as below:

```
structure(list(GRGN_L2 = c("Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia"
), CTR_MN_NM = c("Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan"), UC_NM_MN = c("Zhudong", 
"Luodong", "Luliao"), osm_points = list(structure(list(osm_id = c("3249128823", 
"3351945490", "3351945505", "3765279567", "4364548361", "4364548378", 
"4947856726", "7916339583", "7916339584", "7916358897", "7916358898", 
"7916358899"), shop = c("supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", 
"supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", 
"supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket"), 
    geometry = structure(list(`3249128823` = structure(c(121.0905189, 
    24.73876), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `3351945490` = structure(c(121.0893655, 
    24.7388094), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `3351945505` = structure(c(121.0813833, 
    24.7459191), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `3765279567` = structure(c(121.0846439, 
    24.7444198), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `4364548361` = structure(c(121.0971256, 
    24.734965), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `4364548378` = structure(c(121.0908186, 
    24.7351469), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `4947856726` = structure(c(121.087062, 
    24.7269147), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `7916339583` = structure(c(121.0928898, 
    24.7346181), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `7916339584` = structure(c(121.0918999, 
    24.7232848), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `7916358897` = structure(c(121.0965028, 
    24.7205721), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `7916358898` = structure(c(121.087707, 
    24.7374291), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `7916358899` = structure(c(121.0875757, 
    24.74007), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 121.0813833, 
    ymin = 24.7205721, xmax = 121.0971256, ymax = 24.7459191), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
        input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"World\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c("3249128823", 
"3351945490", "3351945505", "3765279567", "4364548361", "4364548378", 
"4947856726", "7916339583", "7916339584", "7916358897", "7916358898", 
"7916358899"), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(osm_id = NA_integer_, 
shop = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor")), structure(list(osm_id = c("5113153694", 
"5796397687", "6810846801", "6818829872", "6818829884", "7817207409", 
"7928086964", "7999811209", "7999811210", "8025081280"), shop = c("supermarket", 
"supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", 
"supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket"), 
    geometry = structure(list(`5113153694` = structure(c(121.7780721, 
    24.6741645), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `5796397687` = structure(c(121.770755, 
    24.7055799), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `6810846801` = structure(c(121.7712727, 
    24.6802552), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `6818829872` = structure(c(121.7666674, 
    24.6689705), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `6818829884` = structure(c(121.7640656, 
    24.679061), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `7817207409` = structure(c(121.7716792, 
    24.6696471), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `7928086964` = structure(c(121.769175, 
    24.6800347), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `7999811209` = structure(c(121.7713529, 
    24.6824071), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `7999811210` = structure(c(121.7713917, 
    24.6821289), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `8025081280` = structure(c(121.782323, 
    24.6827789), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 121.7640656, 
    ymin = 24.6689705, xmax = 121.782323, ymax = 24.7055799), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
        input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"World\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c("5113153694", 
"5796397687", "6810846801", "6818829872", "6818829884", "7817207409", 
"7928086964", "7999811209", "7999811210", "8025081280"), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(osm_id = NA_integer_, 
shop = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor")), structure(list(osm_id = c("2626683554", 
"3676178589", "4215298011", "4824903523", "5028314123", "5775155946", 
"5776524122", "6045299274", "6510327094", "8000263041"), shop = c("supermarket", 
"supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", 
"supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket", "supermarket"), 
    geometry = structure(list(`2626683554` = structure(c(120.5295901, 
    24.2543299), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `3676178589` = structure(c(120.5300603, 
    24.2412761), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `4215298011` = structure(c(120.5707911, 
    24.2176101), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `4824903523` = structure(c(120.5697318, 
    24.2744302), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `5028314123` = structure(c(120.5691325, 
    24.2727129), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `5775155946` = structure(c(120.5378053, 
    24.2451279), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `5776524122` = structure(c(120.5251238, 
    24.211885), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `6045299274` = structure(c(120.5329863, 
    24.2543002), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `6510327094` = structure(c(120.5482108, 
    24.2438576), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), `8000263041` = structure(c(120.567964, 
    24.2765406), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 120.5251238, 
    ymin = 24.211885, xmax = 120.5707911, ymax = 24.2765406), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
        input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"World\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c("2626683554", 
"3676178589", "4215298011", "4824903523", "5028314123", "5775155946", 
"5776524122", "6045299274", "6510327094", "8000263041"), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(osm_id = NA_integer_, 
shop = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor")))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), groups = structure(list(
    GRGN_L2 = c("Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Asia"
    ), CTR_MN_NM = c("Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan"), UC_NM_MN = c("Luliao", 
    "Luodong", "Zhudong"), .rows = structure(list(3L, 2L, 1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try the base R code below

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    asplit(taiwan, 1),
    function(x) do.call(cbind, x)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
                GRGN_L2 CTR_MN_NM UC_NM_MN osm_points.osm_id osm_points.shop
3249128823 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        3249128823     supermarket
3351945490 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        3351945490     supermarket
3351945505 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        3351945505     supermarket
3765279567 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        3765279567     supermarket
4364548361 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        4364548361     supermarket
4364548378 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        4364548378     supermarket
4947856726 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        4947856726     supermarket
7916339583 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        7916339583     supermarket
7916339584 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        7916339584     supermarket
7916358897 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        7916358897     supermarket
7916358898 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        7916358898     supermarket
7916358899 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Zhudong        7916358899     supermarket
5113153694 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Luodong        5113153694     supermarket
5796397687 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Luodong        5796397687     supermarket
6810846801 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Luodong        6810846801     supermarket
6818829872 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Luodong        6818829872     supermarket
6818829884 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Luodong        6818829884     supermarket
7817207409 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Luodong        7817207409     supermarket
7928086964 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Luodong        7928086964     supermarket
7999811209 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Luodong        7999811209     supermarket
7999811210 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Luodong        7999811210     supermarket
8025081280 Eastern Asia    Taiwan  Luodong        8025081280     supermarket
2626683554 Eastern Asia    Taiwan   Luliao        2626683554     supermarket
3676178589 Eastern Asia    Taiwan   Luliao        3676178589     supermarket
4215298011 Eastern Asia    Taiwan   Luliao        4215298011     supermarket
4824903523 Eastern Asia    Taiwan   Luliao        4824903523     supermarket
5028314123 Eastern Asia    Taiwan   Luliao        5028314123     supermarket
5775155946 Eastern Asia    Taiwan   Luliao        5775155946     supermarket
5776524122 Eastern Asia    Taiwan   Luliao        5776524122     supermarket
6045299274 Eastern Asia    Taiwan   Luliao        6045299274     supermarket
6510327094 Eastern Asia    Taiwan   Luliao        6510327094     supermarket
8000263041 Eastern Asia    Taiwan   Luliao        8000263041     supermarket
           osm_points.geometry
3249128823 121.09052, 24.73876
3351945490 121.08937, 24.73881
3351945505 121.08138, 24.74592
3765279567 121.08464, 24.74442
4364548361 121.09713, 24.73496
4364548378 121.09082, 24.73515
4947856726 121.08706, 24.72691
7916339583 121.09289, 24.73462
7916339584 121.09190, 24.72328
7916358897 121.09650, 24.72057
7916358898 121.08771, 24.73743
7916358899 121.08758, 24.74007
5113153694 121.77807, 24.67416
5796397687 121.77075, 24.70558
6810846801 121.77127, 24.68026
6818829872 121.76667, 24.66897
6818829884 121.76407, 24.67906
7817207409 121.77168, 24.66965
7928086964 121.76918, 24.68003
7999811209 121.77135, 24.68241
7999811210 121.77139, 24.68213
8025081280 121.78232, 24.68278
2626683554 120.52959, 24.25433
3676178589 120.53006, 24.24128
4215298011 120.57079, 24.21761
4824903523 120.56973, 24.27443
5028314123 120.56913, 24.27271
5775155946 120.53781, 24.24513
5776524122 120.52512, 24.21188
6045299274   120.5330, 24.2543
6510327094 120.54821, 24.24386
8000263041 120.56796, 24.27654
```

Comment: To complete the answer of @ThomasIsCoding. Afterwards, you just need to run this line of code to get a sf object : `Supermarket <- st_sf(your.data.frame)`